# Find the top most returning companies?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like: `table(date, name, close)`
Where each `name` has many **unique** `dates`, and each `date` has 1 `close` price. (dates without times)

```
date     name    close
2.3.23   A       100
3.3.23   A       120
2.3.23   B       110
3.3.23   B       90
```

If someone is asking for the top 5 companies with the highest returns in March, I will need to produce a result like

```
name  returns
A     12
B     10.2
```

Where we assume that we are not sure that in `1st March` we had a record(weekend etc) so we need the first available date in march.(could be 2nd)

Also `returns` is `100* (last close - first close)/first close` (first/last of the period)

I started with something like this :

```
SELECT name, ((last_close - first_close) / first_close) * 100 AS return_percentage
FROM (
  SELECT ???
  FROM table
  WHERE date >= '2023-03-01' AND date <= '2023-03-31'
) subquery
GROUP BY name, return_percentage
ORDER BY return_percentage DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: No subquery needed, you could instead roughly do `... FROM yourTable start INNER JOIN yourTable end ON start.name = end.name WHERE start='2023-03-01' AND end='2023-03-31' ...`, keeping your `GROUP BY` in there (without `return_percentage`).

Comment: Why is A not 20, ie (120 - 100) / 100 * 100 = 20?

Comment: @Rogue can you show full code? i am a beginner so i am not sure how to put all of that together :)

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? I see no aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
create table myTable(date date, name varchar(10), close int);
insert into myTable values('2.3.23',   'A',       100);
insert into myTable values('3.3.23',   'A',       120);
insert into myTable values('2.3.23',   'B',       110);
insert into myTable values('3.3.23',   'B',       90);
```

Query:

```
with cte as
(select name,date,close,row_number()over(partition by name order by date) rn,
  row_number()over(partition by name order by date desc) rn2 from myTable
WHERE date >= '2023-03-01' AND date <= '2023-03-31')
select name,100*(max(case when rn2=1 then close else 0 end)-max(case when rn=1 then close else 0 end))/max(case when rn=1 then close else 0 end) returns
  from cte
group by name
```

Output:

| name | returns |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | -18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uAYAmCnX)

You can also use `first_value()over()` window function like below:

Query:

```
with cte as
(select name,date,close,
  100*(first_value(close)over(partition by name order by date desc)-first_value(close)over(partition by name order by date)) /(first_value(close)over(partition by name order by date))  returns
  from myTable
WHERE date >= '2023-03-01' AND date <= '2023-03-31'
)
select name,max(returns)
from cte
group by name
```

Output:

| name | max |
|:-----|----:|
| A    | 20  |
| B    | -18 |
`

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ob4wBoj7)